# Formula for inverse of polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[i,\sqrt{5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

A homework problem from my algebra class:

Find a formula for the inverse of $p + qi + r\sqrt{5} + si\sqrt{5}$ where $p,q,r,s \in \mathbb{Q}$.

I have tried the following approaches:

1) Suppose we know there exists an inverse of the form $t+ui+v\sqrt{5}+wi\sqrt{5}$. Then I use linear algebra to solve for $t,u,v,w$ in terms of $p,q,r,s$. However, the expression I get is unsatisfactory since it is quite long and has a denominator term (the determinant of a matrix) which I would need to show is not equal to zero.

2) I have also tried replicating the formula for finding the inverse of a complex number. Namely, I guessed that the inverse is $p-qi-r\sqrt{5}-si\sqrt{5}$. However, this does not give me the desired cancellation of the $i$ and $\sqrt{5}$ terms. I tried manipulating the above guess, but with no success.

I'm wondering if there is a simple formula for finding this inverse that I am unaware of.

Comment: It might be worth posting whatever answer you got for $1$; given that there's only one correct answer, and your method does find it, it might be that you're overlooking a simplification, or advantageous interpretation of the formula.

Comment: Sure; type the following into WolframAlpha and the solution is the first column of the output:

inverse of matrix {{p,-q,5r,-5s},{q,p,5s,5r},{r,-s,p,-q},{s,r,q,p}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{1}{(p+qi)+\sqrt{5}(r+si)} = \dfrac{1}{(p+qi)+\sqrt{5}(r+si)} \cdot \dfrac{p+qi - \sqrt{5}(r+si)}{p+qi - \sqrt{5}(r+si)}$

$= \dfrac{p+qi - \sqrt{5}(r+si)}{(p+qi)^2-5(r+si)^2}$

$= \dfrac{p+qi - \sqrt{5}(r+si)}{p^2-q^2-5r^2+5s^2 + (2pq-10rs)i}$

$= \dfrac{p+qi}{p^2-q^2-5r^2+5s^2 + (2pq-10rs)i} -\sqrt{5} \dfrac{r+si}{p^2-q^2-5r^2+5s^2 + (2pq-10rs)i}$

Now you just have two divisions of complex numbers that can be handled in the usual way. I admit it's not pretty, but it'll get the job done.